# Reading from a file to a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to read content from a file to which I have written comma separated vales. The first values is a book identification number and the rest are details like author and year published.

The file books.txt content is like this.

```
001,C Programming,John Doe,2001,4

002,Kids story,Kier Alcock,2014,20
```

I want to take this ID number as the key and the rest as its values.
The code I tried so far,

```
details = {}
with open("books.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split(',')
        details[int(key)] = val
        print (details)
```

But it gives me an error ,

```
    (key, val) = line.split(',')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Could you please help me to get each line separately as records and assign first value as key and the rest as the values

Comment: Remove the **braces**, e.g. `key, val =`, but accroding to your `CSV` data you need 5 at the left side.

Comment: Your file has an empty line: no comma to split on

Comment: What is your expected output. It's unclear what you're attempting to do because even fixing the immediate obvious error leads to a non-functioning program

Comment: Actually the empty line in my question is a mistake. In the file the records are separated by new lines only. What I really needed was to print the content by line by line while also assigning the first value as key. I apologize for the my type error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work because there are more than two values in the line:

```
(key, val) = line.split(',')
details[int(key)] = val
```

Instad of that, to read as many values as there are:

```
key, *values = line.split(',')
details[int(key)] = values
```

Or, even better, be explicit, like this:

```
key, title, author, year, something = line.split(',')
details[int(key)] = title, author, year, something
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
details = {}
with open("books.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        values = (line.strip()).split(",")
        details[int(values[0])] = values[1:]
```